# Rails turbo "data-turbo-action: advance", handling refresh, src, and maintaining query params in turbo frames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I have been tasked with refactoring one of our pages which uses ajax, j render, and bootstrap to turbo frames.

The page in question is for a specific *User* model -> `users_controller#show`

In our application a user has many *user_programs* which can be selected by a dropdown. Currently when loading a *user* the first *user_program* is displayed at the bottom of the page if one has not been specified in the url. To accomplish this in turbo I have created the following turbo_frame (in HAML)

```
= turbo_frame_tag 'user_container', 'data-turbo-action': 'advance', src: user_program_path(user_id: @user.id, id: 1)
```

The `src` attribute will autoload the specified path to the user program on the initial page load. Right now I have it hardcoded to 1 however in the future it will need to be a bit smarter, but that's besides the point.

This leads me to my first issues.

**#1 On initial page load the url does not respect the provided src attribute**

When navigating to the `/users/2` endpoint, the url will NOT be changed to `/users/2/user_programs/1` as it would if I were to click on the dropdown manually due to the `'data-turbo-action': 'advance'`. I need to url to be changed so users can share links with each other and go to the correct program, this will be confusing if they have to click on a button to see the same thing they already see just so the url updates.

This leads me cleanly into my second issue

**#2 When refreshing WITH the correct url (/users/2/user_programs/1) only that frame will be displayed to the user**

If the user were to click on the button manually and the correct url was displayed, then they refreshed, a page only containing that frames contents will be returned to the user. Specifically the contents of `user_programs#show`.

I have attempted to guard the requests in the user_programs controller with the methods provided by `Turbo::Frames::FrameRequest` and redirecting (see below).

```rb
redirect_to user_path(id: @user.id) unless turbo_frame_request?
```

However this loses the context of what *user_program* was selected, and again removes the ability for users to share links with each other as they will be redirected to the default *user_program*

Is what i'm looking for even possible?

This leads me to my final question

**#3 If there were query params present in the initial request 'data-turbo-action': 'advance' will remove them**

Other pages in our application will redirect to the `users_controller#show` action with certain query_params, such as `/users/2?booking_id=21`. When clicking on one of the links which pertain to the `user_container` turbo_frame. The query params will be destroyed. Is there any way to preserve them with this attribute set?

I have been wrestling with this all afternoon and have been scouring github and the turbo docs for answers. I want to avoid writing custom logic to handle these scenarios as it seems like something turbo *should* be able to handle out of the box.

Here are the relevant gems

```
turbo-rails (1.3.2)
rails (7.0.8)
```

Any help with any of these questions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way of doing that. Best I came up with is to merge turbo frame `src` parameters with your current url parameters:

```rb
# do whatever you have to do to pass needed parameters to turbo frame
# this will handle the refresh
<%= program_params = params.as_json.slice("user_id", "id").symbolize_keys.with_defaults({id: 1, user_id: @user.id}) %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "user_container",
    src: user_program_path(**program_params),
    data: {turbo_action: "advance_params"}
%> #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# we'll make our own action to only pass parameters and not the full url
```

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

document.addEventListener("turbo:frame-render", (event) => {
  const frame = event.target

  // implement `data-turbo-action="advance_params"`
  if (frame.dataset.turboAction === "advance_params") {
    const url = new URL(location);
    const frameUrl = new URL(frame.src)

    frameUrl.searchParams.forEach((v,k) => {
      url.searchParams.set(k, v);
    })

    history.pushState({}, "", url);
  }
});
```

Now, when you navigate within a frame, current url will be updated with query parameters from the frame `src`. When you refresh the page these parameters will be passed down to the frame `src` url.

It'll be easier to work with query params, so you might want to change this route `/users/2/user_programs/1` to be `/user_programs/1?user_id=2`.